# kotlin -access view from non activity class

Tags: android, kotlin

I've a class that needs to be include in lots of my activities , so I've made a class that needs to access the view . 
this is my code :

```
class Toolbar{
private lateinit var typeface:Typeface;
private lateinit var context:Context
private lateinit var tvToolbar:TextView;

fun MakeToolbar(context:Context, title:String){
    this.context=context
    init();
}

private fun init() {
    typeface= Func.getTypeFace(context)!!

    tvToolbar=((Activity)context).findViewById 

}
```

the problem is , in java I can easily access the context and use findViewById to get my view , Buy I can't do it in kotlin and it couldn't find the view .

How can I access a view in a non activity class?

Comment: There is not much difference between java and kotlin . You are casting in kotlin like this (context as? Activity)?. findViewById(R.id....)   I wrote this just from my memory quickly may be with some error... so really its the same , if that activity has view at time of calling that it will return the same as it would in java code....

Comment: I just want to say you wrote that class really badly... I don't know maybe you should ask or read about kotlin more... I ca write you how it should look like though but it's not related to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `tvToolbar=((Activity)context).findViewById` really your code? It won't event compile in Kotlin, or Java for that matter.

The syntactically correct way would be this:

```
tvToolbar = (context as Activity).findViewById(R.id.tvToolbar)
```

Though I recommend against passing your entire activity object to another class. Why don't you just pass in a reference to your view? And be sure to read about [WeakReferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html).

Comment: thanks for your reply , it solves my problem , but  a question ,this class can contains up to 5 views , is it better to pass view from contexts or get a reference from context ?

Comment: It really depends, but as rule of thumb try to avoid passing `Context` and `View` objects outside your activity or fragment. It is prone to `MemoryLeak`. You should try the MVP or MVVM approach.

Comment: @HamedMomeni May I talk to you in private, please?